# R Shiny: Linked multiple plots with Brush

Tags: r, flexdashboard, shinyjs

I have hotel reservation dataset which consists of "book_date", "check_in", "check_out" and "revenue". I would like to draw 2 charts - "revenue by booking date" vs "revenue by check-in date"; which I could highlight/zoom in particular booking period (says Jan 2018) to understand revenue for corresponding check-in period (says Feb - Apr 2018).

I try to achieve this by incorporating Shiny "brush" in R Flexdashboard. The idea is that, when nothing is "brush" on  "revenue by booking date", "revenue by check-in date" will show a default chart (i.e. revenue for all check-in date). If user zoom in a period in "revenue by booking date", "revenue by check-in date" will react accordingly. However, the default display for "revenue by check-in date" is not working as expected.

Below are my codes:

```
library(flexdashboard) 
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(timetk)
library(scales)
library(plotly)
```

1. revenue by booking date

`shiny::plotOutput(outputId = "revenue_book", brush = brushOpts(id = "brush", direction = "x"))`

```
output$revenue_book <- shiny::renderPlot(
    df %>% filter(book_year == 2018) %>% 
      group_by(book_date) %>%
      summarise(revenue = sum(price)) %>%
      ungroup() %>% 
      ggplot(aes(book_date, revenue)) + geom_line() + geom_point(color = "red") + theme_bw()
  )
```

2. revenue by check-in date

   `shiny::plotOutput(outputId = "revenue_ci")`

   `output$revenue_ci <- shiny::renderPlot({`
   `if (is.null(input$brush)) {`
   `p <- df %>% filter(book_date == 2018) %>%`
   `group_by(check_in) %>% summarise(revenue = sum(price))`
   `%>%  ungroup()`

   ```
    # default chart if no "brushing" on "booking revenue chart"
   ` p %>% ggplot(aes(check_in, revenue)) + geom_line() +`        `geom_point(color = "blue") + theme_bw()}`
   ```

   `else {`
   `q <- df %>% filter(book_date >= input$brush$xmin & book_date <= input$brush$xmax) %>%` 
   `group_by(check_in) %>% summarise(revenue = sum(price)) %>%` `ungroup()`

   ```
    `q %>% ggplot(aes(check_in, revenue)) + geom_line() +` `geom_point(color = "blue") + theme_bw()}})`
   ```

Charts without Brushing

[image]

Charts with Brushing

[image]

Appreciate your advice for what goes wrong as I am new to R Shiny & Flexdashboard.